# Installed Python script cannot import package modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, setup.py

I have created a Python package with the following directory structure:

```
/
 LICENSE
 MANIFEST.IN
 README.rst
 VERSION
 docs/
 multitool/
     __init__.py
     core/
         __init__.py
         classes.py
         utils.py
     libs/
     multitool.py
     tests/
     tools/
         __init__.py
         hashtool.py
         webtool.py
 setup.py
```

The goal is to create a command line application (multitool.py) that 3rd parties can add to by adding their own files to the tools directory.  This is accomplished by having them subclass a class that I've created.  For example, these are the first few lines of hashtool.py:

```
import multitool

class HashTool(multitool.core.classes.CLITool):
```

All of this works as long as I run it from the project directory itself:

```
$ ./multitool.py -h             <---works
$ ./multitool/multitool.py -h   <---works
```

The problem comes when I try to create and install it as a package.  The install runs and installs the script.  However, when you run the script, it cannot find any of the modules in the package:

```
$ multitool.py

import core 

ImportError: No module named core
```

I've tried changing the import to multitool, multitool.core, .multitool, ..multitool, and others with the same result.

However, I *am* able to do imports from the Python interpreter:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multitool
>>> import multitool.core
>>> import multitool.core.classes
>>> from multitool import core
>>>
```

Here is the relevant portion of my setup.py

```
setup(
    name = 'multitool',
    version = __version__,
    license = 'GPLv2',
    packages = find_packages(exclude=['test/']),
    scripts = ['multitool/multitool.py'],
    include_package_data = True,
    ....
)
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I import my own code and the files from the tools directory in the script that I install with the package?

**Updated**
MrAlias's edited comment below worked.  The confusion was that the script was the same name as the package itself and was not in a separate directory.  Moving the script to its own bin/ directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, when you install the package you are importing core without identifying it is being apart of the multitool package.  So:

```
import core
```

should be,

```
from multitool import core
```

That way the interpreter knows the module to import core from.

[Edit]

As for the directory structure of the installed package, scripts need to go into a separate directory from the module itself. The way the shown directory structure is Distutils will install the script you named into both a place your system looks for executables as well as in the package itself, which is likely where all the confusion is coming from.

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried that again and got another ImportError though: ImportError: cannot import name core

Comment: What is the directory structure of you site-packages? And are you running from a virtual environment?

Comment: Yep, this is running inside a virtualenv.  Printing dir(multitool) from within the script only showed the declarations from within the script itself, not from the package.  i.e., multitool.main() was showing, but not multitool.core.  I just tried moving multitool.py to bin/mtcl.py and now I can run "from multitool import core, libs" from within the script.  It all seems to work now so I'm happy, but I guess I don't understand why it wouldn't work the other way.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> import multitool
>
> class HashTool(multitool.core.classes.CLITool):
> ```

Importing a package does not import its subpackages and submodules.  Try this:

```
import multitool.core.classes

class HashTool(multitool.core.classes.CLITool):
```