# Script cannot import installed package, but interpreter can

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Using Windows 10, and Python 3.4.3, with Powershell, and a clean venv:

```
PS C:\Users\nward\MyEnvDirectory .\Scripts\Activate.ps1
(MyScriptVenv) PS C:\Users\nward\MyEnvDirectory pip install Package
[...] Success!
```

I can verify that `C:\Users\nward\MyEnvDirectory\Lib\site-packages\Package` exists and looks good.

```
(MyScriptVenv) PS C:\Users\nward\MyEnvDirectory python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Package
>>>
```

So, that works. However, if I try to run the same line, e.g "import Package" from within a .py file in the same directory, like so -
    `(MyScriptEnv) PS C:\Users\nward\MyEnvDirectory .\main.py` - then I get an `ImportError: No module named 'Package'`.

Based on what I've read, this is usually due to a PATH error, shadowing, or mixing versions of Python. `python --version` gives `Python 3.4.3`, and I don't believe I have any other versions installed. I don't think this is due to shadowing since my script file and the package have different names. So it must be due to a PATH problem, but I don't understand what it is, since the interpreter clearly has no problems with the PATH! This question [Installed Python script cannot import package modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221631/installed-python-script-cannot-import-package-modules) seems to be exactly my problem but it was due to shadowing/directory structure issues. I've also read that this could be a permissions issue (e.g an elevated interpreter but a low-permission executing shell), but the permissions in this case are OK.

Anyone have any suggestions for where I should look next? This is a really basic issue and I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding something, but I'm a little stumped. Thanks!

Comment: what do you get when you do `import sys ; print(sys.path)` , inside your script, where the loading fails.

Comment: You will probably need to add the location of your "Package" in your `PYTHONPATH`. How you do that in Windows I am not sure, but should not be too difficult to find that out. Hope that helps.

Comment: Environment variables result in different PATHs in different places you run Python, so there's likely a discrepancy there. `print sys.path` as Anand suggests and see what results.

Comment: The results are indeed different between the interpreter and the script. Why is this, and how can I get the script's execution environment to be the same as the interpreter? I would've thought that running it from within the activated VENV would've done it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like when you run open python interactive interpreter inside the virtual environment using -

```
PS C:\Users\nward\MyEnvDirectory python
```

You are getting the python installation from the virtualenv, but when you run your script as -

```
.\main.py
```

It is picking up the python outside the virtualenv, since when you directly run the file, windows picks up the python executable that is registered for `.py` files. You can try running the script as -

```
python main.py
```

From within the virtualenv.